# file_exists() works on string but not string variable

Tags: php, file-exists

I have problem with function file_exists() in PHP. Result of code below is always "Exists on string", but in my opinion it should print two messages.

```
$file = 'test_file.txt';
  if (file_exists($file)){
       echo 'Exists on variable';
  }
  if (file_exists('test_file.txt'){
       echo 'Exists on string';
  }
```

Comment: try with absolute path instead of relative

Comment: Suggestion, if you want to check if it actually is a file and it exists, use `is_file()` instead. `file_exists()` will also return true if the path is a folder... and what @ManinderpreetSingh said..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You need to use both to avoid a warning by is_file(). Edit: oh apparently not! https://3v4l.org/L9ppf sorry!

Comment: @jedifans - No, `is_file()` does the same thing, but better. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*is_file* recommended to use to verify files and inconvenience can be for your routes, change

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/test_file.txt';
```

[is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) are two native PHP functions that can be used to verify whether a particular file exists or not. Although their names are fairly descriptive, you should know that:

1. ***is_file*** returns true only if the path to the last function is actually an existing file.
2. ***file_exists*** returns true whether the past is a file path as a valid directory (use is_dir if you want to specifically check if a path is a directory but not a file).

> This difference is very important. If your goal is not only files and directories is_file is your function. If you want to check a directory or a file indifferently choose file_exists

example:

```
$file ='mysite/public_html/folder/file.php';

$directory ='/mysite/public_html/folder/';


$exists = is_file( $file );//return true

$exists = is_file( $directory ); //return false

$exists = file_exists( $file );//return true

$exists = file_exists( $directory ); //return true
```

Comment: This is a good explanation about those to functions. However, it doesn't really answer the OP's question so I'm not sure why you gave it as an answer?

Comment: Will check function is_file. Maybe it will work better in my case :)

Comment: is_file in my problem did the work. It should work this same, but with no reason they didn`t. Now everythink is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some help for the people having this issue: double check your variable to make sure it's correct.

Have you sanitized the input so the characters you are looking for actually match up?

If you are using something like ffmpeg for example you need to put your path in double qoutes, ie a file name can be "myVideo.mp4" rather than myVideo.mp4, meaning that if you pass that as a variable you'd pass '"myVideo.mp4"' rather than 'myVideo.mp4'

are your forward/backslashes correct?

Is your starting directory the one you think it is?

if not, change it with Chdir();